# Rspec examples continue to run in spite of sleep being encountered

Tags: ruby, rspec, sleep

I have the following rspec

```
context "example 1" do
  puts "hello"
  it "example 1 it" do
    sleep(50)
  end
end
context "example 2" do
  puts "thanks"
  it "example 2 it"
end
end
```

When I run this using rake, I get the following output:

```
hello
thanks

example 1
 example 1 it
  <<waits for 50s >>
```

Why is `thanks` printed while it is sleeping for 50s? I expect `thanks` to be printed only after the sleep is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `puts` is being executed as rspec processes your file, not in conjunction to the tests being run.  To prove this to yourself, you could try referencing an undefined local variable after the `it` statement.

For example:

```
context "example 1" do
  puts "hello"
  it "example 1 it" do        
    sleep(50)
  end
  puts "goodbye" + cruel_world
end
```

When you run rspec, you're going to see your "hello", followed by

`An error occurred while loading ./spec/your_spec.rb`

Followed by the NameError from referencing cruel_world.

Comment: Does that mean anything that is written in all the contexts, gets ran first and then the IT blocks get executed sequentially?

Comment: Well, not _anything_ in the contexts.  You could, for example, define a function in a context, and that isn't going to get "run" until you call it.  Also, it's not entirely safe to assume that the `it` blocks are going to get executed sequentially (you can have rspec randomize the order of your tests).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the explanations marc. What my tests are doing is invoking different apis via a method which i call in the context. In the IT block i have the assertions. When i was executing the suite, i could see that all the APIs have been executed and only the assertions are being taken cared of in a sequential manner..

Comment: Marc is correct.  In fact it's generally better to have your tests randomized.  Each unit should pass regardless of test order.  If not, it indicates the design is defective.